# How to observe properties of observable class

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I have the following class

```
public class A extends java.util.Observable {
private B property1;
private C property2;
int variable1;

/*Setters and getters**/
}
```

I made this class Observable so that I can be notified for any changes in variable1. Now I want to be notified for changes in the variables inside the properties of type B or C. Since the variables of properties B and C are not changed from the setter methods in class A I cannot notify the Observer when a change occurs.

What is the best way to notify the observer without registering explicitly the classes B and C in the observer code ? I just want to observe all the properties which are part of class A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call one of the of the [`notifyObservers()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#notifyObservers%28java.lang.Object%29) methods when your `Observable`'s state changes. They might not be modified by setter methods explicitly, but if you've properly [encapsulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) the access to your `B` and `C` objects then you should be good to go.

It sounds to me, though, like you are allowed the references to `B` and `C` to continue to exist outside your class `A` object. The effect of this is that your system is now depending on the implementation of class `A`, rather than it's interface. Work around this by:

1. **Preferred** Not allowing the rest of your system to have access to class `B` and `C`, and have to work everything through class `A`

   - [Read more about the Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_Of_Demeter) about why you should do this, rather than allowing other classes to get references of `B` and `C` directly.
2. **Hack** Make `B` and `C` also extend `Observable`, and have them update `A` when they change as well.

---

Code sample

```
public class A extends java.util.Observable {
  private B property1;
  private C property2;
  int variable1;

  public void doThatThingy() {
    property1.doSomething();
    notifyObservers();
  }
}

public class B {
  void doSomething() {
    // Hey look at me, I'm doing something
  }
}
```

### DO NOT DO

```
public B getB() {
  return property1;
}
```

Comment: I can't figure out how I can understand when the Observable state has changed. The client's will use the getter method to get access in property1 for example and then they will modify the internal fields using its setters and getters.

Comment: @Stefanos I have significantly edited this post since I first wrote it. Code sample incoming

Comment: Thank you very much now I understand what you mean :-)